# Create a new instance in a static function of an abstract class

Tags: php, abstract-class, abstraction, instantiation

```
abstract class db_table {

    static function get_all_rows() {
        ...
        while(...) {
            $rows[] = new self();
            ...
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}

class user extends db_table {

}

$rows = user::get_all_rows();
```

I want to create instances of a class from a static method defined in the abstract parent class but PHP tells me "Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class ..." How should I implement it correctly?

Edit: Of course I want to create instances of the class "user" in this case, not of the abstract class. So I've to tell it to create an instance of the called sub-class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) in the manual:

> Limitations of `self::`
>
> Static references to the current class
>   like `self::` or `__CLASS__` are resolved
>   using the class in which the function
>   belongs, as in where it was defined.

There is only an easy way around this using PHP >= 5.3 and late static bindings.  In PHP 5.3 this should work:

```
static function get_all_rows() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        while(...) {
            $rows[] = new $class();
            ...
        }
        return $rows;
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Comment: Hint: The get_called_class can be emulated in PHP < 5.3 by using this code: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php#93799

Answer (score 9):

this work for me..

```
abstract class db_table {

static function get_all_rows() {
    ...
       while(...) {
           $rows[] = new static();
           ...
       }
       return $rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, liked it a lot!